# Convert an expression with radicals into simpler form

Tags: radicals, cubics

It was pointed out in a mathologer [video on the cubic formula](https://youtu.be/N-KXStupwsc)   that $\sqrt[3]{20 + \sqrt{392}} + \sqrt[3]{20 - \sqrt{392}}$ is actually equal to $4$. Is there a series of transformations that can be done to reduce the above expression with radicals to $4$ ?

I realise that writing $x= \sqrt[3]{20 + \sqrt{392}} + \sqrt[3]{20 - \sqrt{392}}$ and cubing both sides gets us to $x^3 = 40 + 6x$ and it's easy to **verify** that 4 is a solution. Is there a way to **arrive** at $4 $instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way is very fine, as an alternative we have that by

- $20 + \sqrt{392}=(u+\sqrt v)^3$
- $20 - \sqrt{392}=(u-\sqrt v)^3$

and then

$$(u+\sqrt v)(u-\sqrt v)=u^2-v=\sqrt[3]{(20 + \sqrt{392})(20 - \sqrt{392})}=\sqrt[3]8=2$$

that is $u^2-v=2$, therefore

$$20 + \sqrt{392}=\left(u+\sqrt {u^2-2}\right)^3=4u^3-6u+(4u^2-2)\sqrt {u^2-2}$$

that is

- $2u^3-3u=10 \iff (u-2)(2u^2+4u+5)=0 \iff u=2$
- $(4u^2-2)\sqrt {u^2-2}=14\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{392}$

then $v=2$ and

- $20 + \sqrt{392}=(2+\sqrt 2)^3$
- $20 - \sqrt{392}=(2-\sqrt 2)^3$

which finally leads to

> $$\sqrt[3]{20 + \sqrt{392}} + \sqrt[3]{20 - \sqrt{392}}=2+\sqrt 2+2-\sqrt 2=4$$

Answer (score 2):

OP's solution is the simpler and more direct one, with the following observation.

> cubing both sides gets us to $x^3 = 40 + 6x$ and it's easy to verify that $4$ is a solution

It is not enough that $4$ is a solution to prove that $x=4$. What matters here is that $4$ is the *only* real solution, so the *real* root $x$ must be equal to $4$.

Mostly for fun, here is another way, to derive the same result. Let $\,a,b = 20 \pm \sqrt{392}\,$, then $\,a + b = 40\,$ and $\,ab = 8\,$, so $\,a,b\,$ are the roots of the quadratic $\,t^2 - 40 t + 8\,$. It follows that $\,\sqrt[3]{a}, \sqrt[3]{b}\,$ are among the roots of the sextic resulting from the substitution $\,t = u^3\,$, which very conveniently happens to factor as:

$$
u^6 - 40 u^3 + 8 = (u^2 - 4 u + 2) (u^4 + 4 u^3 + 14 u^2 + 8 u + 4)
$$

The quartic factor has no real roots, because:

$$
u^4 + 4 u^3 + 14 u^2 + 8 u + 4 \;=\; (u+1)^4 + \frac{1}{2} (4 u + 1)^2 + \frac{5}{2} \;\gt\; 0
$$

Therefore the real numbers $\,\sqrt[3]{a}, \sqrt[3]{b}\,$ must be the roots of the quadratic factor $\,u^2 - 4 u + 2\,$, so by Vieta's relations $\,\sqrt[3]{a} + \sqrt[3]{b} = 4\,$.